# Using JavaScript in Browser's Bookmarklet to Edit the URL with Regex

Tags: javascript, web, url, browser, bookmarklet

So I know it's possible to run JavaScript by storing them in the browser's bookmark (aka. [bookmarklet](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-are-bookmarklets/)), but I'm not sure if it's possible to use bookmarklet to auto-edit the current URL (and then bring you to the new URL).

What I'm trying to do:

In the URL, replace everything before (**and including**) the string

```
/image/thumb/
```

with

```
https://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/0/
```

and remove everything after (**and including**) the **last**

```
/
```

So for example, the following URL:

```
https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/4e/61/09/4e610911-7e0e-d348-8246-11ef6ffe00ab/886443607118.jpg/540x540bb.webp
```

should become (and redirect to)

```
https://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/0/Music/v4/4e/61/09/4e610911-7e0e-d348-8246-11ef6ffe00ab/886443607118.jpg
```

after clicking on the bookmark with JavaScript.



Some more examples:

```
https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Features122/v4/b0/26/80/b0268001-9527-3477-1df2-c68f02271a9f/ffe8be4a-2798-4a68-b691-9a91edb1c177.png/216x216sr.webp
```

should become (and redirect to)

```
https://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/0/Features122/v4/b0/26/80/b0268001-9527-3477-1df2-c68f02271a9f/ffe8be4a-2798-4a68-b691-9a91edb1c177.png
```

---

```
https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Video124/v4/ac/c2/b0/acc2b0a3-8105-2f22-2b0d-ea274223e959/Jobe81235fa-44f7-43f8-a7d6-421093c13e0b-110141253-PreviewImage_preview_image_nonvideo_sdr-Time1616098999993.png/300x300.jpg
```

should become (and redirect to)

```
https://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/0/Video124/v4/ac/c2/b0/acc2b0a3-8105-2f22-2b0d-ea274223e959/Jobe81235fa-44f7-43f8-a7d6-421093c13e0b-110141253-PreviewImage_preview_image_nonvideo_sdr-Time1616098999993.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.prototype.match(regExp)` to get the url part which you want and then combine the url part with your url prefix.

```
function replaceUrl(url) {
   const prefix = 'https://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/0';
   const lastPart = url.split("/image/thumb/")[1];
   const match = lastPart ? lastPart.slice(0, lastPart.lastIndexOf("/")) : null;
   const targetUrl = match ? `${prefix}/${match}` : url;
   return targetUrl;
}
const targetUrl = replaceUrl('https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/4e/61/09/4e610911-7e0e-d348-8246-11ef6ffe00ab/886443607118.jpg/540x540bb.webp');
```

Add a bookmarklet, the bookmarklet's script is like:

```
javascript:(function(){
  function replaceUrl(url) {
   const prefix = 'https://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/0';
   const lastPart = url.split("/image/thumb/")[1];
   const match = lastPart ? lastPart.slice(0, lastPart.lastIndexOf("/")) : null;
   const targetUrl = match ? `${prefix}/${match}` : url;
    return targetUrl;
 }
 const targetUrl = replaceUrl(location.href);
 window.open(targetUrl,"_blank");
})()
```

The `location.href` is the url of current tab, you can change it to whatever you need (may be url from links of current page etc.).
the second parameter of `window.open()` could be `_blank`(open in a new tab) or `_self`(open in current tab)

Comment: But how do I incorporate that into a browser's bookmark to make it retrieve and change the URL?

Comment: It's not possible in my opinion. Bookmark is a browser tool, there's no way to control it by javascript. but you can configure your server to redirect current url to new url.

Comment: It's certainlly possible and it's known as Bookmarklets:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-are-bookmarklets/
I even have one working in my Bookmark. I just couldn't figure out how to do the things I described.

Comment: i'm confused.  you want to add a bookmarklet yourself or  provide such an 'adding bookmarklet' way to users? The bookmarklet must be added manually and one bookmarketlet goes to one url , because when you click the bookmarklet, how do you know the origin url? you must write the origin url precisely in your javascript codes. besides, there's no programmable way to add a bookmarklet

Comment: I was trying to add a bookmarlet myself, for example, the following bookmarklet removes the toolbar from Youtube videos:

javascript:(function(){var goaway=".ytp-gradient-bottom,.ytp-gradient-top,.ytp-chrome-top,.ytp-chrome-bottom{display:none;}";if("\v"=="v"){document.createStyleSheet().cssText=goaway}else{var tag=document.createElement("style");tag.type="text/css";document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);tag[(typeof document.body.style.WebkitAppearance=="string")?"innerText":"innerHTML"]=goaway}})();

The above bookmarklet doesn't need to contain any URL to work

Comment: ok, that makes sense,i've edited my answer,hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like your script was written before I edited the part about what strings to replace/remove (my original idea about replace/remove was flawed). Could you see if you could edit your script accordingly? (The first two examples indeed work with your current script, but I've added a 3rd example in the last part, which is an exception that doesn't work with your current script. You can probably see why my original idea was flawed from that example.)

Comment: change `reg` to `/\/(Music|Features).*\.(jpg|png)/`, if you know all the prefixes and picture formats, you can extend the regexp like `(Music|Features|someOtherPrefix...)` and `(jpg|png|someOtherFormat...)`

Comment: That doesn't work when the original URL also ends with .jpg or .png (it also might not even be an image, so using .jpg or .png might not always work). The "Prefix" can be many various things besides "Music" or "Features", so it's hard to include all of them. (Please see another last example I just added.) That's why I figured out using "/image/thumb/" and "last /" (as described in the Question) is the best idea that works with everything.

Comment: The new way of converting worked like a charm, thanks so much